# Dynamic TextView onClickListener Android

Tags: android, dynamic, onclick

I'm adding an `onClickListener` to a dynamic `TextView` with a `CompoundDrawable` and it doesnt seem to be working.

**CODE**

```
for (Product p: mProductList) {     
    ...     

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    if (bmp != null) {
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
        textView.setText(name);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, d, null, null);
        textView.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        textView.setTag(unique);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setOnClickListener(mProductListener);
        mProductCarousel.addView(textView, sortOrder);
    }
}

mProductListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("TESTING", "CLICKED");
        String productId = String.valueOf(v.getTag());
        Log.v("PRODUCT ID", productId);
    }
};
```

The `TextView` with `Drawable` are added to the layout with no problem, but the click event is not firing. I never receive either Log message. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure. This is just a hunch let me know if it pays of:

```
if (bmp != null) {
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
    textView.setText(name);
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, d, null, null);
    textView.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    textView.setTag(unique);
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    textView.setOnClickListener(mProductListener);
    mProductCarousel.addView(textView, sortOrder);
}
```

If it doesn't try the alternative:

```
textView.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: i'll be back in 20 minutes, trying it then. Thanks

Comment: Nope, tried both, neither worked. I thought you may of been on to something though. The root layout has an `onTouchListener` and I thought that may of had something to do with it.

Comment: @Jawascript so you have visible,  clickable text views with attached listeners and still they are not fired? if so,  try with a simplest text view and narrow the root of the problem

Comment: im thinking the problem has to b from your constructive code block.. maybe try to repost some key codes attach to wat you have idk,, yu brought up the assumption..idk..

Comment: @pskink thats right. I will try and perform some simple testing.